# Android DataBinding Inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-databinding

I have the following code for my layout and my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ScanFragment">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

```
class ScanFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentScanBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        FragmentScanBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).also {
            binding = it
        }.root

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding.cameraPreview
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to access the cameraPreview view directly from the binding. I have already added the pre-requisites for DataBinding below:

```
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

and

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

inside the gradle.properties

Comment: The issue is that the binding is not populating views from the fragment's layout, so I should be able to access the cameraPreview view from what I understand. The binding itself though has a correct value, but the compiler is not recognizing the subviews.

Comment: What version of the AndroidGradlePlugin are you using?

Comment: My Gradle plugin version is showing as: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

Comment: Try removing `android.databinding.enableV2=true` it isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Still no luck after removing the flag and Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: try 
`binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false)`
`return binding.root`

Comment: I've been trying the other DataBinding class alternatives with no luck either unfortunately

Comment: After a massive series of reboots / cleans, it seems to be working! Yikes, Android. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataBindingUtil

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_scan, container, false) 
return binding.root
```

Comment: From what I've seen DataBindingUtil and the generated class (FragmentScanBinding) should be interchangeable, but I would definitely believe issues might come up with using the generated class

Comment: `ViewDataBinding` documentation says: "If possible, the generated binding should be instantiated using one of its generated static bind or inflate methods. If the specific binding is unknown, `DataBindingUtil.bind(View)` or `DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater, int, ViewGroup, boolean)` should be used"